How to unit test AWS Glue scripts using pytest, Dynamic frames and Data frames?
I want to unit test my AWS Glue scripts. I am using Python and Pyspark. I want to unit test functions that utilise Dynamic frames and Data frames. I don't need to interface with AWS or data on AWS. I want to essentially assert the content of the frames is correct for these small testable functions.
I was hoping to setup a pytest fixture that would be a Spark Session with GlueContext. I was hoping I could do this just using Python dependencies e.g. pyspark and awsglue-dev but I am getting issues.
My conftest fixture looks like this:
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def spark_context():
    spark_ctx = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
    spark_ctx.setLogLevel("WARN")
    return spark_ctx

@pytest.fixture
def glue_context(spark_context):
    glue_ctx = GlueContext(spark_context)
    return glue_ctx

The errors I am getting look like this:
test setup failed
spark_context = <SparkContext master=local[*] appName=pyspark-shell>

    @pytest.fixture
    def glue_context(spark_context):
>       glue_ctx = GlueContext(spark_context)
if min_partitions is None:
>           return self._jvm.GlueContext(self._jsc.sc())
E           TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable

Can anyone please advise on what the issue is here? Does my AWS Glue local dev/test setup need to be different or more than just installing the Glue and PySpark dependencies via PDM/PyPi?
Thanks,
Sam

A whole Glue/Spark environment is needed. This can be achieved using a Docker container or installing the aws-glue-libs and Spark on your local machine. The instructions here eventually worked BUT they dont tell you that you need Java 8 Openjdk installed first - see Developing locally with Python here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html
